# How to highlight/match (but not search!) the word under cursor

Tags: highlight

I am searching some pattern, navigate between search results, and at the same time I want some other pattern to be highlighted. For example, I jump between invocations of some function in my project, usually there is a variable named "session" around and I want this word to be highlighted.

What I do is:

```
:match StatusLineTerm /session/
```

where `StatusLineTerm` is just a name of existing highlight group having the color I like.

The question is: how to create some key combination that would call this `match` command using the word under cursor as a match pattern? Something like `nnoremap <F5> :match StatusLineTerm /.expand(<cword>)/`, but actually working?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For a quick solution, try this:

```
:nnoremap <F5> :match StatusLineTerm /<C-R><C-W>/<CR>
```

This uses <kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-W</kbd> to insert the word under the cursor into the command line. See `:help c_CTRL-R_CTRL-W`.

Answer (score 7):

Here's how you do this automatically after keeping your cursor still for a short time:

```
:au CursorHold * :exec 'match Search /\V\<' . expand('<cword>') . '\>/'
```

By default, this will highlight the word under the cursor after 4s of inactivity. Use `:set updatetime=100` to make it happen after 0.1s instead.

If you want to do this in a script instead of as a one-off, put it in an autogroup so that you don't add a new `CursorHold` autocommand every time the script runs:

```
augroup highlight_current_word
  au!
  au CursorHold * :exec 'match Search /\V\<' . expand('<cword>') . '\>/'
augroup END
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! You might want to show this with an autogroup, since that is best practice.

Comment: I definitely would not want to do it, but thanks a lot, it's cool trick to know about!

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Good idea, done.

Answer (score 6):

I use a plugin for that: [interesting words](https://github.com/lfv89/vim-interestingwords). It's not big, since it's only feature is to highligh words with defined or random colors, advantage is that you can have more than one color/highligh under single key. You can easly clear all the highlights done with that plugin if needed as well.

Comment: Not exactly what I want (f.e. I no NOT want to navigate between the interesting words), but it's something to investigate or may be use.

Answer (score 5):

I use the [mark.vim](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1238)-plugin for this. It can handle many interesting words at the same time and allows to jump between highlighted words.

Answer (score 3):

You indicate that you were trying to get the mapping to work with `<cword>`. Though the answer you accepted is just fine I'm surprised no one answered with a corrected use of that.

Normally the string on the RHS of a mapping is executed  literally as an Ex command. No pre- expansion/evaluation/processing of the string occurs. So `:match` in

```
:nnoremap <F5> :match StatusLineTerm /.expand(<cword>)./
```

(along the lines of your attempt) will try to literally match the string '*.expand(<cword>).*'

If we want the string or some portion of it to be expanded/evaluated we have to do it ourselves by passing it to the `:exec` command as an expression:

```
:exec 'match StatusLineTerm /' . expand('<cword>') . '/'
```

Note that we surround with quotes any parts that we want to use literally and append them with `.`. The rest is evaluated. (Also note that `<cword>` is a special string and needs to be quoted before being passed to `expand()`.)

So, the mapping you were originally going for is:

```
:nnoremap <F5> :exec 'match StatusLineTerm /' . expand('<cword>') . '/'<CR>
```